# Passing JSON object into a list

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to programming and have a json object with data related to a coin. I want to take the data from the json object and display it using google charts. However I can't seem to be able to get it working. Any input is appreciated.

Json object

```
    [{"id":1,"CoinValue":"0.01","Count":82,"CoinWeight":76},
{"id":2,"CoinValue":"0.02","Count":86,"CoinWeight":18},
{"id":3,"CoinValue":"0.05","Count":29,"CoinWeight":42},
{"id":4,"CoinValue":"0.1","Count":35,"CoinWeight":90},
{"id":5,"CoinValue":"0.2","Count":23,"CoinWeight":3},
{"id":30,"CoinValue":"0.5","Count":41,"CoinWeight":36}]
```

Coin class

```
    public class Coin
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CoinValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int CoinWeight
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

}
```

Coin Model:

```
public class CoinModel
    {
        public IList<Coin> coins;
    }
```

Coin Controller: I suspect the Data method is what needs to be changed to add each record into the list

```
        // GET: Coin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"H:\EasyAsPiMVC\EasyAsPiMVC\App_Data\MOCK_DATA.json");
        var coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinModel>>(fileContents);



        return Json(coins);
    }
```

View

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "Json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Data", "Coin")',
        success: function (result) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                drawChart(result);
            });
        }
    });

    function drawChart(result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "CoinValue"); //might have to be changed
        data.addColumn("number", "Count");
        var dataArray = [];
        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            dataArray.push([obj.CoinValue, obj.Vounter]);
        });
        data.addRows(dataArray);

        var piechart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker Piechart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };

        var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
        piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);

        var barchart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker barchart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML of view:

```
<body>
    <table class="columns">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="piechart_div" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
            <td><div id="barchart_div" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></div></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: All that is displayed is 2 blank google charts. No error seems to be showing

Comment: Don't add to your question via comments.  A question should be a fully contain question without the need of comments to be answered.  You can always edit your own question.

Comment: Open your browser developer tools and look for the ajax request.  Verify that it is returning with a success code (200-399) and that the response is what you think it is.

Comment: @Taplar what is the exact response coming back from your server ? You are currently returning a list of CoinModel objects ?

Comment: @Kalvinl8 can you post a screenshot of the console window of your browser?

Comment: @Kalvinl8 what is the exact response coming back from your server ? You are currently returning a list of CoinModel objects. Is it a list of one item ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is returning a list of `CoinModel` objects and in the `$.each` loop, you are accessing each item's `CoinValue` and `Vounter` properties. But the `CoinModel` object has only one property, which is `coins`, which is a list of `Coin` objects.

All you have to do is to make sure the data you are sending and your `$.each` code matches.  For example, if you action method is returning a list of `Coin` objects, you may loop through them at client side and access each item's `CoinValue` property value

```
public ActionResult Data()
{
    var coins = new List<Coin>
    {
        new Coin() {Count = 1, CoinValue = "Aa",CoinWeight = 50},
        new Coin() {Count = 2, CoinValue = "Bb",CoinWeight = 20},
        new Coin() {Count = 3, CoinValue = "Cc",CoinWeight = 30}
    };
    return Json(coins);
}
```

Now at the client side, you will loop through this json array and then you can access the `CoinValue` and `CoinWeight` property of each item and use that to build the other array which you need for rendering the chart

```
var dataArray = [];
$.each(result, function (i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([obj.CoinValue, obj.CoinWeight]);
});
data.addRows(dataArray);
```

Comment: Okay thanks that makes more sense! However my data comes from a json object so i do not want to hard code the list like you have. How do i get around this?

Comment: That is y i asked what is the exact structure of data your action method is returning ? Based on the structure, you need to update your client side code.